# How could I crop image in exact location where numbers are situated?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-recognition, python-tesseract

I have my code prototype:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('/home/follia/Pictures/scan.jpg')

h, w, k = img.shape
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((w / 2, h / 2), 15.5, 1)
img = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (w, h))

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 100, 200, apertureSize=3)

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 80)
for x in range(0, len(lines)):
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[x]:
        cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)

cv2.imshow("origin", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Original image:
[image]
and it return this image:
[image: image I get]

And I need this image to be cropped and show only numbers: 
[image: image I need]

Could you please help me out, how could I cut this location?
And then, how could I recognize numbers and extract it from image to text?

Comment: could you please post the original unannotated `scan.jpg` as well? That'll make it easier to test solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

Basic idea of this solution is, get the contours of the image after performing `threshold()` and detect the biggest contour among contours.

**INPUT:**

[image]

**CODE:**

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("test.jpg", 1)
h, w, k = image.shape
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((w / 2, h / 2), 15.5, 1)
image = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h), cv2.INTER_LINEAR, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue=(255, 255, 255))

img = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
threshold = 80
cv2.threshold(img,threshold,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,img)
cv2.bitwise_not(img,img)
cv2.imshow("Result", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
im2, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

if len(contours) != 0:
    #find the biggest area
    c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
    crop_img = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    cv2.imshow("Result", crop_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imshow("Result", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! much appreciated! But there is still one thing, I have to rotate it before cropping, so I'm using getRotationMatrix2D and warpAffine and after it cropped the wrong part of image

Comment: I just added this :
h, w, k = image.shape
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((w / 2, h / 2), 15.5, 1)
image = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h))

Comment: Could you please post the original input image. Otherwise It is hard to continue.

Comment: added original photo

Comment: thank you very much! but now I have to recognize those numbers into text, could give some advice how could I do it? should I use NN or something else? But pytesseract won't work with this image :(

Comment: further preprocess this image in order to get it recognized using pytesseract